# Pandas selecting discontinuous columns from a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am using the following to select specific columns from the dataframe comb, which I would like to bring into a new dataframe. The individual selects work fine EG: comb.ix[:,0:1], but when I attempt to combine them using the + I get a bad result the 1st selection ([:,0:1]) getting stuck on the end of the dataframe and the values contained in original col 1 are wiped out while appearing at the end of the row. What is the right way to get just the columns I want?  (I'd include sample data but as you may see, too many columns...which is why I'm trying to do it this way)

```
comb.ix[:,0:1]+comb.ix[:,17:342]
```

Comment: Are you trying to add them column-wise? try `pd.concat([comb.ix[:,0:1],comb.ix[:,17:342]], axis=1)`

Comment: Bingo, make it and answer, Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: This may be getting a little cute, but could also do something like:  ```comb.ix[:,[0]+range(17,343)]```

Comment: I think we can also use numpy.r_ refer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41256648/select-multiple-ranges-of-columns-in-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to concatenate a sub selection of your df columns then use `pd.concat`:

```
pd.concat([comb.ix[:,0:1],comb.ix[:,17:342]], axis=1)
```

So long as the indices match then this will align correctly.

Thanks to @iHightower that you can also sub-select by passing the labels:

```
pd.concat([df.ix[:,'Col1':'Col5'],df.ix[:,'Col9':'Col15']],a‌​xis=1)
```

Note that [`.ix`](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/whatsnew.html#deprecate-ix) will be deprecated in a future version the following should work:

```
In [115]:
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['col' + str(x) for x in range(10)])
df

Out[115]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [col0, col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9]
Index: []

In [118]:
pd.concat([df.loc[:, 'col2':'col4'], df.loc[:, 'col7':'col8']], axis=1)
​
Out[118]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [col2, col3, col4, col7, col8]
Index: []
```

Or using `iloc`:

```
In [127]:
pd.concat([df.iloc[:, df.columns.get_loc('col2'):df.columns.get_loc('col4')], df.iloc[:, df.columns.get_loc('col7'):df.columns.get_loc('col8')]], axis=1)

Out[127]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [col2, col3, col7]
Index: []
```

Note that `iloc` slicing is open/closed so the end range is not included so you'd have to find the column after the column of interest if you want to include it:

```
In [128]:
pd.concat([df.iloc[:, df.columns.get_loc('col2'):df.columns.get_loc('col4')+1], df.iloc[:, df.columns.get_loc('col7'):df.columns.get_loc('col8')+1]], axis=1)

Out[128]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [col2, col3, col4, col7, col8]
Index: []
```

Comment: you can also use labels with .ix like this...

e.g. pd.concat([df.ix[:,'Col1':'Col5'],df.ix[:,'Col9':'Col15']],axis=1)

Comment: @ihightower thanks for the suggestion, I've updated the answer to also show how to achieve this using `loc` and `iloc` as `.ix` will be deprecated in the future

Answer (score 9):

NumPy has a nice module named [r_](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html), allowing you to solve it with the modern DataFrame selection interface, iloc:

```
df.iloc[:, np.r_[0:1, 17:342]]
```

I believe this is a more elegant solution.

It even support more complex selections:

```
df.iloc[:, np.r_[0:1, 5, 16, 17:342:2, -5:]]
```

Comment: This is the best answer.

Answer (score 4):

I recently solved it by just appending ranges

```
r1 = pd.Series(range(5))
r2 = pd.Series([10,15,20])
final_range = r1.append(r2)
df.iloc[:,final_range]
```

Then you will get columns from 0:5 and 10, 15, 20.