# Select multiple ranges of columns in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have to read  several files some in Excel format and some in CSV format. Some of the files have hundreds of columns.

Is there a way to select several ranges of columns without specifying all the column names or positions? For example something like selecting columns 1 -10, 15, 17 and 50-100:

```
df = df.ix[1:10, 15, 17, 50:100]
```

I need to know how to do this both when creating dataframe from Excel files and CSV files and after the data framers created.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

use [`np.r_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html)

```
np.r_[1:10, 15, 17, 50:100]

array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 15, 17, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55,
       56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72,
       73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89,
       90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99])
```

so you can do

```
df.iloc[:, np.r_[1:10, 15, 17, 50:100]]
```

Comment: This also works for filtering rows. Very nice, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I find @piRSquared 's answer straightforward.

You may also use:

```
Locs = list(range(0,10)) + [14, 16] + list(range(49, 100))
# columns 1 -10, 15, 17 and 50-100
# [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 14, 16, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99]

df = df.iloc[:Locs]
```

Answer (score -3):

use inner join
like
result = pd.concat([df1, df4], axis=1, join="inner")

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.