# Python + Pandas : Copying specific columns of the first row of multiple CSVs and store the rows to a single csv

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have about 190 CSV's. each of which has same column names. A sample csv shared below:

[image]

From **every** csv, I need to pick **only** the `Item`, `Predicted_BelRd(D2)`, `Predicted_Ulsoor(D2)`, `Predicted_ChrchStrt(D2)`, `Predicted_BlrClub(D2)`,
`Predicted_Indrangr(D1)`, `Predicted_Krmngl(D1)`, `Predicted_KrmnglBkry(D1)`, `Predicted_HSR(D1)` **columns** of only the **first row**, and need to store all these rows to a separate CSV. So the final CSV should 190 rows.

How to do that?

**Edit:**
Code so far, as suggested by DavidDR:

```
path = '/home/hp/products1'
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
#print(all_files)

columns = ['Item', 'Predicted_BelRd(D2)', 'Predicted_Ulsoor(D2)', 'Predicted_ChrchStrt(D2)', 'Predicted_BlrClub(D2)', 'Predicted_Indrangr(D1)', 'Predicted_Krmngl(D1)', 'Predicted_KrmnglBkry(D1)', 'Predicted_HSR(D1)']

rows_list = []
for filename in all_files:
    origin_data = pd.read_csv(filename)
    my_data = origin_data[columns]
    rows_list.append(my_data.head(1))

output = pd.DataFrame(rows_list)
#output.to_csv(file_name, sep='\t', encoding='utf-8')
output.to_csv('smallys_final.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

**Edit2 :**
The original dataframe:

```
prod = pd.read_csv('/home/hp/products1/' + 'prod[' + str(0) + '].csv', engine='python')
print(prod)
```

Output:

```
      Category                         Item  UOM  BelRd(D2)  Ulsoor(D2)  \
0  Food/Bakery  BAKING POWDER SPARSH (1KGS)  PKT          0           0   
1  Food/Bakery  BAKING POWDER SPARSH (1KGS)  PKT          0           0   
2  Food/Bakery  BAKING POWDER SPARSH (1KGS)  PKT          0           0   
3  Food/Bakery  BAKING POWDER SPARSH (1KGS)  PKT          0           0   
4  Food/Bakery  BAKING POWDER SPARSH (1KGS)  PKT          0           0   

   ChrchStrt(D2)  BlrClub(D2)  Indrangr(D1)  Krmngl(D1)  KrmnglBkry(D1)  \
0              0            0             0           0               1   
1              0            0             0           0               0   
2              0            0             0           0               0   
3              0            0             0           0               0   
4              0            0             0           0               1   

   HSR(D1)         date  Predicted_BelRd(D2)  Predicted_Ulsoor(D2)  \
0        0    10 FEB 19                  0.0                   0.0   
1        0    17 FEB 19                  NaN                   NaN   
2        0    24 FEB 19                  NaN                   NaN   
3        0   4 MARCH 19                  NaN                   NaN   
4        0  11 MARCH 19                  NaN                   NaN   

   Predicted_ChrchStrt(D2)  Predicted_BlrClub(D2)  Predicted_Indrangr(D1)  \
0                      0.0                    0.0                     0.0   
1                      NaN                    NaN                     NaN   
2                      NaN                    NaN                     NaN   
3                      NaN                    NaN                     NaN   
4                      NaN                    NaN                     NaN   

   Predicted_Krmngl(D1)  Predicted_KrmnglBkry(D1)  Predicted_HSR(D1)  
0                   0.0                       0.0                0.0  
1                   NaN                       NaN                NaN  
2                   NaN                       NaN                NaN  
3                   NaN                       NaN                NaN  
4                   NaN                       NaN                NaN  

    3        0   4 MARCH 19  
    4        0  11 MARCH 19
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
def function():
    firstrows = []  # to collect 190 dataframes, each only 1 row
    for filename in csvnames:
        # read CSV, filter for a subset of columns, take only first row
        df = pd.read_csv(filename) \
             .filter(["Item", "Predicted_BelRd(D2)", ...]) \
             .iloc[:1]
        firstrows.append(df)
    return pd.concat(firstrows)
```

Comment: NameError: name 'csvnames' is not defined

Comment: You have to set this to the list of your csv files! It is just a skeleton code.

Answer (score 1):

Didn't check but this should work.

You basically read all you csv files from the same location, then you choose only the relevant columns. Then you pop out the first row and append it to a list of all the first rows. in the end you create a new DataFrame from the first row's list and you save it to one csv file.

```
import glob
import pandas as pd

path = # use your path
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")

columns = ['Item', 'Predicted_BelRd(D2)', 'Predicted_Ulsoor(D2)', 'Predicted_ChrchStrt(D2)', 'Predicted_BlrClub(D2)', 'Predicted_Indrangr(D1)', 'Predicted_Krmngl(D1)', 'Predicted_KrmnglBkry(D1)', 'Predicted_HSR(D1)']
rows_list = []
for filename in all_files:
    origin_data = pd.read_csv(filename)
    my_data = origin_data[columns]
    rows_list.append(my_data.head(1))

output = pd.DataFrame(rows_list)
output.to_csv(file_name, sep='\t', encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: Getting this error: KeyError: "['Predicted_BelRd(D2)' 'Predicted_Ulsoor(D2)' 'Predicted_ChrchStrt(D2)'\n 'Predicted_BlrClub(D2)' 'Predicted_Indrangr(D1)' 'Predicted_Krmngl(D1)'\n 'Predicted_KrmnglBkry(D1)' 'Predicted_HSR(D1)'] not in index"

Comment: @Debbie are you sure the columns name from the CSV file match the one in the `columns` list?

Comment: Yes, sure. Check the attached photo once. Instead of column name can we use column index by any means?

Comment: @Debbie please look here: [select multiple ranges of columns in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41256648/select-multiple-ranges-of-columns-in-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: @Debbie in any case the `not in index` error is due to mismatch with the columns name... you can try to remove some of the columns from the `columns` list and try until you figure out what column is the bad one...

Comment: all the columns appear in the error statement seems to be the bad columns. I am clueless what is happening as exactly the same name occur  in the source csvs.

Comment: That's what u suggested only. Check the edit portion.

Comment: Can you try and print one of the original dataframes (the one you receive from the `pd.read_csv(filename)` command) and share the output? I only need the there top lines...

Comment: see if you can get only one column, lets say `item`. use this code: `new_prod = prod['item']` and print it: `print(new_pord)`