# Select range of columns by condition in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'd like to do something like this. Pick one or n column ranges and another column

`df_premises = df.iloc[:, 0:8 and 11]` equivalent to `df_premises = df.iloc[:, [0,1,2,3,,8,11]]`

I've tried;

1. `df_premises = df.iloc[:, 0:8, 11]` - causes error
2. `df_premises = df.iloc[:, 0:8 + 11]` - returns 0:18

Comment: Also answered by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41256648/select-multiple-ranges-of-columns-in-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use: `df.iloc[:, lambda x: x.index < 9 or x.index == 11]`

Simpler solution will to define a list before that, and use the list inside `iloc`.

For example:

```py
my_range = range(9)
my_range.append(11)
df_premises = df.iloc[:, my_range]
```

as mentioned in [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html), input must be one of the following:

> 1. An integer, e.g. 5.
> 2. A list or array of integers, e.g. [4, 3, 0].
> 3. A slice object with ints, e.g. 1:7.
> 4. A boolean array.
> 5. A callable function with one argument (the calling Series or DataFrame) and that returns valid output for indexing

You can use simple slicing like `df.iloc[:3]` or a function like `df.iloc[lambda x: x.index % 2 == 0]`.

So specific for what you asked about, following will work:

`df.iloc[:, lambda x: x.index < 9 or x.index == 11]`

Comment: Thanks is this the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41256648/select-multiple-ranges-of-columns-in-pandas-dataframe ?

Comment: Same but different ways. Both works, use what is simpler for your opinion. For you case I like the more direct use of lambda

Answer (score 0):

Exaple: When ***row number 300 achieves a condition***, the code outputs **[270:300]** number of rows:

Makes windows from the condition

```py
MINUTES_BEFORE_FOR_WINDOW_TIME = 30
rows_valid  = df_s[df_s['valid'] ==1 ].index #condition 
rows_valid_bef = [ np.r_[ i - MINUTES_BEFORE_FOR_WINDOW_TIME: i +1 ] for i  in rows_valid ]
df_s = df_s.iloc[np.concatenate(rows_valid_bef) ]#one dimension
```